Check if a subdomain is in a list of subdomains and use a different proxy_pass depending on if the subdomain is in the list. Using wildcard
I want to serve an old version of a node app to the users that already created a subdomain.
New users will receive new subdomains and see a new version of the app.
The old app is on port 8090.
The new app will listen on port 8091.
I will put the new version on a new branch with a different remote that listens on port 8091.
So I’m not sure how to include a list array of subdomains
And do an if condition for the proxy pass.
Existing nginx conf file has details like this
server{

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx - debian.html;
    server_name *.example.com example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
         #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
....
}



pseudo code.
Maybe I want to do something like this
var listOfSubDomains  = ["app1", "app2"]
if(listOfSubDomains.includes(<incomingSubdmain>)){
    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}else{
    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8091;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}

I have about 500 existing subdomains.

You could just use two server blocks.

How can I detect old domains? I have 500 old domains that I want to go to a different port

You question title says "using wildcard" - what do you mean by that? Can the 500 old domains be described using a wildcard representation, or are they all distinctly unique?

I put an example of the wildcard in the first codeblock

Use two server blocks.
server {
    # old domains (all subdomains except mentioned in next server block)
    server_name .example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

    # ...
}

server {
    # new domains
    server_name new1.example.com new2.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8091;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

    # ...
}


The whole point of using wild cards is to not have to manually enter each subdomain. After reading your answer I was thinking of pasting in a list of 500 old domains and having that go to the old port. I didn't think about that
